# Specify logstash configuration on command line with docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash 6.0 documentation for [Stashing your first event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/first-event.html#first-event) shows the following command to run logstash with a simple pipeline which simply pipes stdin to stdout:

> ```
> $ bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
> ```

This does however not work when running logstash from the official docker container and fails with an error message about incompatible command line options:

```
$ docker run --rm -it docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.0.0 \
  -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
ERROR: Settings 'path.config' (-f) and 'config.string' (-e) can't be used simultaneously.
```

I'm not specifying `-f` or `path.config`. I simply want to test if logstash can be started and is working for this simple case. How to get around this error without mounting a config file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking into the startup scripts inside the logstash docker image, one can find the following function in the `logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb` file:

```
# where can I find the logstash.yml file?
# 1. look for a "--path.settings path"
# 2. look for a "--path.settings=path"
# 3. check if the LS_SETTINGS_DIR environment variable is set
# 4. return nil if not found
def fetch_settings_path(cli_args)
  if i=cli_args.find_index("--path.settings")
    cli_args[i+1]
  elsif settings_arg = cli_args.find {|v| v.match(/--path.settings=/) }
    match = settings_arg.match(/--path.settings=(.*)/)
    match[1]
  elsif ENV['LS_SETTINGS_DIR']
    ENV['LS_SETTINGS_DIR']
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

So the solution seems to either pass `--path.settings=` (`=`-syntax with empty value) or set the `LS_SETTINGs_DIR` variable to a falsy value. And indeed:

```
$ docker run --rm -it docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.0.0 \
  --path.settings= -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'
The stdin plugin is now waiting for input:
```

Answer (score 0):

As Knittl stated --path.settings is consulted for logstash settings which are in a logstash.yml file that looks something like this (taken from the docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.1.2 image:

`http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme`

The problem is the path.config points to a directory containing only the default logstash.conf.

The solution with no side effects is:

`$ docker run --rm -it docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.0.0 \
  --path.config="" -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'`

This way the other settings in logstash.yml will persist.